# spfx pnpjs people picker error

Tags: spfx, pnpjs

I am getting an error when running my spfx webpart with a picker picker control. When I do gulp server I get the error

ERROR:

> Cannot find module 'ControlStrings'

I have googled this and have added `ControlStrings`: "node_modules/@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/loc/{locale}.js" to `config.json` file but get the same error.

Full error as follows:

> Error: Cannot find module 'ControlStrings'
> at webpackMissingModule (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:113406:45)
> at ql+0 (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:113406:134)
> at **webpack_require** (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:20:30)
> at Module.ZFCQ (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:75176:120)
> at **webpack_require** (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:20:30)
> at /4uW (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:1674:108)
> at **webpack_require** (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:20:30)
> at 891W (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:19804:82)
> at **webpack_require** (https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:20:30)
> at https://localhost:4321/dist/pn-pjs-example-web-part.js:84:18

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by uninstalling and reinstalling pnpjs react controls.